# Get a message, when mail is open

Tags: python, email

From the below code, I am sending mail with some info.Here i need to get the message to my mail id,When he/she opens the mail.
How to do this in Python.

```
def Data(request):
    templateName = "sendmail.html"
    mapDictionary = {'fromMail': "xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com", 'password': "xxxxx", 'toMail': "yyyyy.yyyy@gmail.com@gmail.com",
                        "subject": "New Trip Confirmation", 'username': 'Ramesh','trip_start_date' : '2014-02-10',
                        'trip_start_place' : 'Visak', 'trip_start_time' : '11:00 AM', "templateName" : templateName
                    }
    print ("call send mail from processNewTripData...")
    return sendmail(request, mapDictionary)


def sendmail(request, mapDictionary):
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(mapDictionary["fromMail"],mapDictionary["password"])
        context = Context(mapDictionary)
        html_content = render_to_string(mapDictionary["templateName"], context)   
        #text_content = "This is Confirmation mail"       
        msg = MIMEText(html_content,'html')
        msg['Subject'] = mapDictionary["subject"]
        server.sendmail(mapDictionary["fromMail"], mapDictionary['toMail'], msg.as_string())
        to_json = {'result' : "True"}
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(to_json), content_type='application/json')
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)
    to_json = {'result' : "False"}
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(to_json), content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a try and add this header:

```
Disposition-Notification-To: "User" <user@user.com>
```

The reader may need to confirm that you get a reply. Also adding html content served by your server can be an option to recognize that the mail is read.

You should be able to do this with any of these lines

```
msg['Disposition-Notification-To'] = '"User" <user@user.com>'
msg['Disposition-Notification-To'] = 'user@user.com'
```

Comment: Is there any example code?.How to use Disposition-Notification-To: "User" <user@user.com>

Comment: Added most probable example.